# Insert extra TH/TD while still maintaining layout in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to fill in some extra stuff in an already existing table. Only problem is I don't know how to do that without without destroying the whole layout.

The table is constructed in an ordinary fashion:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Header</th>
  <th>Header</th>
  <th>Header</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Data</th>
  <th>Data</th>
  <th>Data</th>
 </tr>
</table
```

Have tried to illustrate with an image..

[image]

How do I implement the extra TH and TD, as seen on the image, while still maintaining the structure and layout?

Comment: Probably not the way to win the beautiful code contest but I'd make a table within that TD

Comment: It’s not ordinary to use `th` (instead of `td`) for table data cells.

Comment: I know Jukka, the copy/paste went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the relevant cells by two cells and add `colspan=2` to other cells in the same column. In effect, you would break one column to two columns but so that on some rows, one cell spans both columns. You just need to take care of setting the widths of the new cells so that their combined width plus the spacing between them does not exceed the width of the original column.

Comment: Ok, see your point. Can this be done also when there is dynamic data involved? Just thinking that the inputs will stretch depending on the data and that setting a fixed width will crash the layout. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that you are using normal (not fixed) table layout and would like to have the combined width of the two new columns equal the width of the original column? It might be best to post that as a new question, with sufficient code (sample of a table and the related CSS) shown in the question.

Comment: Yes exactly. The table width expand depending on the content, haven't set any procentage or px. Will post that as a new question, thank you!